# How to get random datetime of current day in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am working on a SQL query where I need to get datetime of any specific date.
For this I used the following query:

```
DECLARE @RandomDate datetime
DECLARE @fromDate datetime = '2018-04-07'

SELECT 
    @RandomDate = (DATEADD(day, ROUND(DATEDIFF(day, @fromDate, @fromDate) 
* RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), 5), DATEADD(second, CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 24000, @fromDate))) 

SELECT @RandomDate
```

Here in the above example, I want to get datetime of date '2018-04-07' i.e 7 April. But sometime it is showing datetime of 6 april also. How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to go 'back-in-time' would be to add a negative number.  Try adding `ABS` to your query.

```
DECLARE @RandomDate datetime

DECLARE @fromDate datetime='2018-04-07'


SELECT @RandomDate= (DATEADD(day, ROUND(DATEDIFF(day, @fromDate, @fromDate) 
* RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), 5),DATEADD(second, abs(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 86400, 
@fromDate))) 

SELECT  @RandomDate
```

[ABS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/abs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) - A mathematical function that returns the absolute (positive) value of the specified numeric expression. (ABS changes negative values to positive values. ABS has no effect on zero or positive values.)

Comment: when i used the above query it is showing datetime below 7AM of current date. It is not showing time above 7am.

Comment: I played around a little with your query - when i changed your fixed 24000 number in the DateAdd for seconds to 86400 (the number of seconds in a day), I get more random times.  Perhaps that will work for you.

Comment: now it fine for me.Thanx

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of your question is that you would like to obtain a random datetime for a particular date.
You can try this:

```
DECLARE @maxval decimal(6,5), @minval decimal(6,5)
SELECT @maxval=1.000,@minval=0.000

SELECT CAST(CAST(DATEADD(second,0,GETDATE()) AS INT) + CAST(((@maxval) - @minval) *
    RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + @minval AS decimal(6,5)) AS Datetime)
```

This will give a random datetime for "today" (i.e. GetDate())

Basically I am reducing today's date to being just a date (no hours / minutes specified) and converted to a number (43213 for today which is 2018-04-25)
then I add a decimal number between 0 and 1 to it, which has the effect of adding hours, minutes, and seconds to that date value.
In other words, random generate any decimal number between 43213 and 43213+1

I hope this helps,

B